# How do I setup a systemd service to be started by a non root user as a user daemon?

Tags: arch-linux, user, rtorrent, systemd

I just finished the install and setup process of systemd on my arch-linux system (2012.09.07). I uninstalled `initscripts` (and removed the configuration files).

What I want to do is create a service that can be started and stopped by a non-root user. The service is to start a detached screen session running rtorrent. However I want every user on the system who has set this service to start (enabled) to have a particular instance started for them specifically. How would one go about doing this?

I remember reading that systemd supports user instances of services, however I have been unable to find any information on how to set this up, or whether it relates to what I am looking for.

Service file that I have used for system:

```
[Unit]
Description=rTorrent

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -d -m -S rtorrent /usr/bin/rtorrent
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall -w -s 2 /usr/bin/rtorrent
```

**UPDATE#1**:

After reading through the man pages [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) and [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), I understand how systemd works a bit better. Specifically that using the `User=` and `WorkingDirectory=` options allow for the service to be started in a user's session. However the issue still remains that the user themselves can not `start`, `stop`, `enable`, or `disable` the service. An *Access is denied* error is given by `systemctl`.

**UPDATE#2**:

First off, for simplification and for better use of systemd's user session (still somewhat incomplete) feature, I used [sofar's user-session-units](https://github.com/sofar/user-session-units) and followed his config advice.

It seems that there is a bug in the current version of DBus (1.6.4-1) in which it does not set the environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` meaning using the `systemctl --user` command errors out with:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

The variable should look like this:

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/USERUID/dbus/user_bus_socket"
```

where *USERUID* needs to be the UID of the given user.

Comment: I realize that one could create a separate service file per user, and simply enable it. However I just want to know if it could be possible the way I have described it above.

Comment: Fair enough, I could simple setup `sudo` for the users and have them, as mentioned in my comment above, control their own service file. However this solution would allow the user to control most other services as well...

Comment: It wouldn't, if you had read `sudo`'s documentation – *sudoers(5)* has many examples on restricting a command's arguments.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

systemd normally does not allow ordinary users to start system services. While it does support giving access via polkit, that part is still somewhat lacking, and you cannot yet allow only one specific service.

*(Edit: Later systemd versions do support it, but only with polkit v106 or later.)*

Since rtorrent is not actually a system service, and because you want every user to have their own instance of rtorrent, experiment with systemd's "user" mode.

When you log in, the system will start a `user@<uid>.service` system unit for you, which will launch a separate "--user" instance of systemd. The new user-systemd will read unit files (starting with `default.target`) from `~/.config/systemd/user/`, `/etc/systemd/user/` and `/usr/lib/systemd/user/`.

Comment: Thanks grawity, that was basically what I was missing. However it also turns out to have been a DBus problem as well: there seems to be a bug in dbuse that doesn't set the correct global variable  `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` for a given user, so systemctl can't access the user session, it errors our. Once I figured out this small problem, everything else works beautifully!

Comment: @Hans and what was the solution to setting `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`? This problem still persist...

Comment: @BojanP. see my UPDATE2 in the question, basically `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` should be set to a user specific dbus socket.